# Tick Tuple not functioning in apache storm 0.9.4

Tags: apache-storm

I have recently migrated storm version from 0.8.2 to 0.9.4. In 0.8.2 I had implemented tick tuple functionality in a bolt in my code.

When I used to run the topology it used to trigger periodic activity after the time specified in tickfrequency seconds (configured in `getComponentConfiguration` method).

But the same piece of code is not running in apache storm version 0.9.4. The code inside if block in execute method is never getting executed because `isTickTuple` method is always returning false.

The other functionalities are working perfectly in apache storm 0.9.4 but tick tuple is not functioning as expected. Can you help?

Comment: can you post the code snippets on how you are currently doing it?

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/utils/TupleUtils.java for distinguish tick tuple and apply it to help you well.