# Apache storm: tick tuple not working

Tags: apache-storm

In my Storm based application I need to query oracle table periodically So I thought to use Tick tuple of storm. But it's not giving correct result and tick tuple is not producing.

My storm version is 1.0.1.2.5.3.0-37

I tried as below,

1. Added getComponentConfiguration method in bolt as http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/01/18/implementing-real-time-trending-topics-in-storm/ link but tick tuple is not generating.
2. So I changed the code and used Config from topology for generating tick tuple.I refer https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/01/06/multi-threading-storm/ link but here I got tick tuple only once.

Below is my code of tick tuple with bolt,

```
public class TickTupleBolt implements IRichBolt{

private OutputCollector collector = null;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TickTupleBolt.class);

public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;     
}

public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    LOG.info("Start of TickTupleBolt.execute");     
     try {
            if (isTickTuple(tuple)) {
            //if(tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals("__tick")){
                LOG.info("**got tick tuple");
            }else{
                LOG.info("not got tick tuple");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Bolt execute error: {}", e);
            collector.reportError(e);
        }       
     LOG.info("End of TickTupleBolt.execute");

}

public void cleanup() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    // configure how often a tick tuple will be sent to our bolt
    Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 1);
    return conf;
}

protected boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
        && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}


}
```

I got one link [Tick Tuple not functioning in apache storm 0.9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157555/tick-tuple-not-functioning-in-apache-storm-0-9-4) but there is no answer.

So can any body please let me know,

1. How to implement tick tuple in Storm
2. Is there any other way (apart from tick tuple) to do periodic job in storm

**UPDATE - Topology Code**

My Topology builder,

```
public class Topology {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Topology.class);

public static StormTopology buildTopology() {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("tickspout", new TickTupleSpout());
    builder.setBolt("tickbolt", new TickTupleBolt()).shuffleGrouping("tickspout");

    return builder.createTopology();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException {
    Config conf = new Config();
    //conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 5);//tried it also
    conf.setDebug(true);
    //conf.setNumWorkers(2);
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, buildTopology());
}

}
```

**UPDATE - Spout Code**

```
public class TickTupleSpout extends BaseRichSpout{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TickTupleSpout.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private SpoutOutputCollector collector;

public TickTupleSpout() {

}

public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
        SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LOG.info("Start of TickTupleSpout.Open");
    this.collector = collector;
    LOG.info("End of TickTupleSpout.Open");
}

public void nextTuple() {
    LOG.info("Start of TickTupleSpout.nextTuple");
    this.collector.emit(new Values("0");//just send dummy value
    LOG.info("End of TickTupleSpout.nextTuple");

}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("breachdata")); 
}

//public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      //Config conf = new Config();
      //int tickFrequencyInSeconds = 5;
      //conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, tickFrequencyInSeconds);
      //return conf;
//}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: tuple.getSourceComponent() and tuple.getSourceStreamId() always return spout name and default values. Help please.

Comment: How are you putting this bolt within your topology? Can we see your topology builder? I suspect that you might not be sending other stuff to the bolt so storm shorts the process and stops emitting the ticks. But to prove that, we would need to see your topology builder. You can also try emitting other tuples to the bolt randomly to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I updated my topology. Please let me know in case any other change. Ultimately I got frustrated and using redis. Also can you please tell me how to emit "other" tuples.

Comment: Ignore the "other" tuples part for now. Let's just get this working. Do you also have your spout code? Sorry it took me 2 days to reply.

Comment: I think your problem might be that you have `getComponentConfiguration` in the bolt code. That is supposed to be in your spout emitter or collector code (I forget which subclass of the spout but you can check the spout interface for reference).

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I tried getComponentConfiguration in Spout also, but it did not work for me. I extended spout from BaseRichSpout. My spout code is also updated.

Comment: A couple things: Why the extra internal `public TickTupleSpout()` declaration? Also, I noticed `getComponentConfiguration` is commented out. Did you get an error or something when it was included? In other words, how are you defining "not working" at this point?

Comment: Hi, getComponentConfiguration  was added in Spout but it did not worked for me. It didn't enable for ticks for me. So I commented out. Also when I say its not working because tuple.getSourceComponent() and tuple.getSourceStreamId() always return spout name and default values instead of __system and __tick, as mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: And just to be clear, "default values" means that "0" that you're emitting from the spout, correct?

Comment: Also, have you tried storm 1.1? I see at least 2 tick tuple fixes in that release. http://storm.apache.org/2017/03/29/storm110-released.html

Comment: Yeah, I am also thinking it could be because of STORM version.  STORM-2387 is interesting for my problem. But I also have seen examples on net with STOMR 0.9 version explaining tick tuple.

Comment: Interesting, try the different version and get back to me. I'm dying to know how this turns out. :)